# Memory reported by Spyder already at large value after starting it

Tags: macos, memory, spyder

I am using Spyder 4.0.1 on MacOS, but when I launch it from Anaconda Navigator, I see at the bottom right of the screen that the memory is already at 73%. Restarting the kernel does not work. I have no idea what do do, it has never happened before.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) That's the total memory used by the different applications in your system, not the memory consumed by Spyder alone. So if you want to reduce that, you need to restart your computer or buy more RAM.